# HTML-CSS: span inside button aligning right

Tags: css, button, alignment, html

I am having trouble with the alignment of a `span` contained within a `button` tag.

I have already done something like this before and it worked. In fact, it's the same css but different sizes.

The problem is that the containing `span` seems to be aligning to the right.

[image]

CSS:

```css
#closePreviewBtn {
    position: absolute;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    right: 0;
    background: #B9DEFD;
    border-top: solid 1px #333333;
    border-left: solid 1px#333333;
    border-right: solid 1px #333333;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333333;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#closePreviewBtn .close {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(../imagenes/close.png) no-repeat center;
    padding: 0;
    /*right: 2px; 
    bottom: 1px;*/ //This fixes the problem but it's manual
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="closePreviewBtn" name="closePreviewBtn"><span class="close"></span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have aligned it to right in your `#closePreviewBtn { right: 0;
 }`. So wats the problem?

Comment: I dont mean the button. The button should be right aligned. I mean the content inside the button, in this case the X image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the button still has some padding after resizing it to 10px. I found no way to set that space off.

The solution i've foud to center it was removing the button height and width, because it will expand to wrap the `span` and it will be centered.

For some weird thing, it works for small buttons. But for bigger buttons like 30px x 50px it will just be fine to set height and width, or at least the padding is very very hard to notice if there's some.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix - seems like the button has a padding by default. Just set it to 0:

```css
#closePreviewBtn {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Now you can position however you want - maybe adding a margin to the span if you want to move it around.

Hope that helps you,

Answer (score 0):

In your `#closePreviewBtn` rule, remove the `right:0;`. Setting the position to absolute and right to zero will take the element out of the document flow and position it as far to the right as possible.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z2VyQ/)**